# Using Parse backend with a calendar view iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, mbcalendarkit

I'm trying to develop an app in objective-c that uses Parse as a backend database and has a calendar in it. I have the user base down and I'm trying to use the open source MBCalendarKit to be able to add events to Parse. I don't know if this is a good way of doing things and I'm wondering if it is even possible to add an event from a calendar to Parse in iOS, and if MBCalendarKit is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Even though Parse is going away, this question might help those with a different backend, so here's the scoop.

You don't create events in MBCalendarKit, but in your own data model. Once you've created your own data model and saved it to your local or remote data store, you can update the calendar UI.

I designed MBCalendarKit to model UITableView's delegation and data source protocols so you can tell it to reload whenever your async methods finish working. Just remember that you would need to do that from the main thread.